# Access Denied to Google Apps Script deployment via OAuth2 for non-Management group member

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-oauth

I've developed a Google Apps Script associated with a Google Sheets document and deployed it with access restricted to members of my organization. The script resides in a document that is exclusively accessible by the Management group within our Google Workspace.

A colleague of mine (let's call him John) is able to invoke the script directly through his browser, despite not being a member of the Management group. He invokes the script by navigating to the URL the script has been deployed to (`https://script.google.com/macros/something/exec`). Here he receives the expected JSON result from the script.

However, when he attempts to call the script programmatically from another Google Sheet using OAuth2 (https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2) for authentication, he encounters an access denied error and gets a login page as response.

Adding John to the Management group resolves the issue, and he can then successfully make the call.

Here's how I've configured the OAuth2 client and made the call to the Apps Script:

```
var service = OAuth2.createService('Google')
      // Set the endpoint URLs.
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth')
      .setTokenUrl('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token')

      // Set the client ID and secret.
      .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
      .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)

      // Set the name of the callback function that should be invoked to
      // complete the OAuth flow.
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())

      // Set the scope and additional Google-specific parameters.
      .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')
      .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
      .setParam('prompt', 'consent')
      .setParam('login_hint', Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());

var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/something/exec';

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
  }
});
```

I'm puzzled as to why John can access the script directly via a browser but not programmatically through OAuth2, and why adding him to the Management group seems to be a workaround. John is not part of the company's management and should not need to be a member of the Management group.

I've tried expanding the OAuth2 scope but I can't find the correct scope to include.

Questions:

1. Why does John face an access denied error when calling the script programmatically via OAuth2, despite being able to access it directly through the browser?
2. Is there a specific OAuth2 scope or configuration I'm missing that would grant John programmatic access without needing to add him to the Management group?
   Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How was the script called programmatically? and how was it invoked through the browser?

Comment: @CenturyTuna - I've edited the question above. I hope this helps?